# Hudson - build.xml doesn't exist

Tags: java, ant, hudson, war, build.xml

I've got the strangest behaviour on Hudson. After downloading the project from svn, i'm trying to trigger ant build, in particular "deploy-war", but Hudson can't see the build.xml file even though the file exists in workspace dir. The thing is when i trigger 'deploy-ant' from cmd, it builds .war file just fine.

[image: Hudson workspace]

[image: Hudson console output]

And this is the way i invoke ant:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strangest thing. The problem had nothing to do with Hudson nor ant, the issue was that the machine i was working on, had cmd.exe starting location in "regedit" set to some strange location, and thus cmd.exe was looking for a build file in that location.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the option **build file** only if the build file name is different from build.xml, say deploy.xml or build1.xml. If the build file name is build.xml and it is exactly in the workspace directory, you don't have to mention **build file**. You can leave this option blank.

If you still want to mention the build file, you have to mention the absolute path of the build file.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Dipu, i'm aware of the fact that ant is looking for the build.xml file in the workspace of the current project and that u don't have to explicitly mention build.xml, my problem is that ant can't see that file.

Comment: Have you tried the above? Giving build file blank or giving absolute path of the build file?

Comment: I've tried leaving it empty, specifying the full path, nothing works, keep getting the same msg "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!" i wouldn't post the question without exploring all the possible options...